# Django : Exception Value 'str' object has no attribute 'resolve'

Tags: python, django

I migrated my localhost `Django project` to an `Ubuntu server`.
I'm working with `Django 1.10.5` and I get a pretty strange error :

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://172.30.10.112/

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'BirthCertificate',
 'Identity',
 'bootstrapform',
 'Accueil',
 'captcha',
 'django_countries',
 'log',
 'Mairie']
Installed Middleware:
['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  172.         resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in resolve
  272.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'resolve'
```

But, If I press `Enter` one more time in my URL bar, I can access to my Django website.

This is my urls.py file :

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from BirthCertificate import views
from Identity import views
from Accueil import views
from log import views
from Mairie import views
from Accueil.views import main_view

urlpatterns = [ 
url(r'^$', main_view, name='index'),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^BirthCertificate/', include('BirthCertificate.urls')),
url(r'^Identity/', include('Identity.urls')),
url(r'^Accueil/', include('Accueil.urls')),
url(r'^Home/', include('log.urls')),
url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
url(r'^Mairie/', include('Mairie.urls')),

]
```

My **main_view** function from Accueil application :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from django.shortcuts import render, reverse, redirect

def Accueil(request) :

    return render(request, 'Accueil.html')

def main_view(request):
    return redirect('/Accueil/accueil/')
```

**Accueil urls.py :**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accueil/', views.Accueil, name="accueil"),
]
```

Comment: please also show the included urls. I suspect it's in thre

Comment: Ok I'm editing my question

Comment: one of those views.xxx isn't pointing to what you expect it to be. The simplest way to solve this is to vomment out all the entires in the main urls.py and then to add them back one by one

Comment: What does the `Accueil` view do? (Please also try to only include relevant information, I've removed the urls that don't appear directly relevant to your question and are still available to view in the edit history of your question)

Comment: Ok sorry Sayse. My accueil view is just my Django website homepage. When users want to go to my website, they are directed on this html page. Because to connect to my application, I have to write : 172.30.10.112/Accueil/accueil/ for example. But I just want (for the moment) write IP adress and be redirected to /Accueil/accueil/

Comment: Yes, but what exactly is inside it? does navigating to that url work correctly?

Comment: Yes it works well. But I have to refresh two or three time to access on my website and doesn't display the error. Accueil is the website homepage with just HTML template as application. Sorry if my answer is not clear. English is not my native langage :/

Comment: It looks like there might be something wrong with one of the included `urls.py`. Maybe one of the files has a `url_patterns` that contains a `str` instead of only url objects? Something like this, perhaps `url_patterns = [r'foo', url(r'/bar', views.bar)]`

Comment: @HåkenLid `main_view` in my project urls.py ? I just see this string ^^

Comment: I mean `Maire/urls.py`, `captcha/urls.py` etc. The resolve function will try to test all the urls in all your apps.

Comment: This error came when I added url line about main_view. It works before but I had to write http://172.30.10.112/Accueil/accueil/ instead of http://172.30.10.112/ as now

Comment: I rebooted my server and it seems to work now immediatly